# Design ideas for passing data out of Salesforce

Tags: ajax, winapi, salesforce, apex-code

Within salesforce, we're envisioning someone clicking on a quote button on an Account object record and having that pass a number of fields information to 1 of two systems. One system would be a web application. The other, a windows application. I was thinking it would be a JavaScript call to the systems, but I'm not sure. What are some of my potential options? How would you guys go about doing this?

Thanks and sorry it's so broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outbound messaging is a great approach and I'd choose that direction for single SObject integrations when possible. However, if you need to pass any form of related list (master-detail/lookup relationship) you'll need to tackle this another way since outbound messaging [only fires on a single object at a time](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_setting_up.htm#api_om_defining). You can configure multiple outbound messages to get around this but this can quickly become unmanageable. JavaScript is certainly doable but using SOAP or REST from within Apex is more sturdy and secure.

I prefer REST/HTTP since Apex has had trouble consuming complex WSDL from external systems. In fact Apex is [not able to consume the Force.com API or the Metadata API](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Importing-WSDL-into-Salesforce/m-p/55256/highlight/true) for size reasons. But the built-in HTTPRequest/HTTPResponse classes from Apex using either the built-in XMLStream/DOM or System.JSON classes to parse results works really well imo.

Comment: All great points, thanks. I'll definitely make sure I have a good think before I implement.

Answer (score 5):

One thing to look into is [Outbound Messaging](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging.htm) in Salesforce.  Outbound messages are triggered as part of a [workflow rule](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_wfrules.htm).  I think you'll find outbound messaging to be a much more robust solution than an AJAX call to a web service.  For instance, if your web service cannot process an incoming request, the outbound message will queue up on the Salesforce side.  Then Salesforce will attempt to resend the message at regular intervals.